# Позиционирование в мобильных браузерах

Tags: html, bootstrap

Вопрос вот в чем, есть горизонтальная менюшка у которой пункты меню в мобильных браузерах не по центру (немного выше), но в обычных браузерах все нормально

Comment: Покажите код `css` и `html` если не жалко